# How to enable multiple ports on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

When I visit http://localhost ,use htdocs1

But if I visit localhost:81,use htdocs2,how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use multiple [Listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) statements and read Apache httpd's documentation on [Binding](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/bind.html).